# Were MOSFETs ever called just "MOSTs"?

Tags: mosfet, history

In the paper "Ion-implanted complementary MOS transistors in low-voltage circuits", the word MOSFET doesn't appear at all, as far as I can tell. Instead, Swanson and Meindl use the "MOST" term.

Are they the same thing? If so, how historically "MOST" turned into "MOSFET" and why?

Comment: Yes, "MOST" is just short for "MOSFET". Why? To not have to type the "FE" (mosFEt). You might be overthinking this and underestimating people's lazyness.

Comment: IGFET, JUGFET etc...

Comment: I think you'll find this in the 1960s,70s. MOSTly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The acronym MOS (Metal-Oxide-Semiconductor or Metal-Oxide-Silicon) was coined by John Moll in 1959 [59] who moved to Stanford from Bell Telephone Laboratories a year earlier."

"...There were many names and acronyms proposed and used for the metal-oxide-silicon field-effect transistors. Eight are known to this author. They give an amusing glimpse of the intensity of competition, not only at the marketplace but also in engineering and scientific disclosures, within one company and among companies.

Fairchild's October 1964 data sheet (Fig. 8) called it the MOS Field-Effect Transistor. Fairchild's November 1964 application bulletin (Fig. 10) called it MOS FET with a space, sometimes half-space between the two groups of letters. Fairchild's October 1964 AM radio circuit application paper (Fig. 11) called it MOST, an acronym coined by Sah appeared in the draft version of the Wanlass-Sah ISCC CMOS paper issued as a Fairchild technical report [91]. It seemed Fairchild engineers could not make up their minds. Wanlass and I knew that MOST is the "most" but our marketing department was not convinced and prefered other names or acronyms. When our boss Gordon Moore heard about it, he exclaimed, "MOST - what a name!,' which probably eliminated its appearance in the title of our CMOS paper... However, Sah was persistent and used it in his next one-author MOSFET paper in 1964 [96].
...
MOSFET, originated from the Fairchild marketing department in October 1962, has been the general consensus for the past decade... But, younger engineers and writers from the orient have frequently used the first and original acronym MOST."

Above quotes from a great paper on the history of MOSFETS, including terminology. ["Evolution of the MOS transistor -From conception to VLSI." Chih-Tang-Sah](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/16328)

*More sources on the usage of either term being equivalent in the literature.

**The metal–oxide–semiconductor field-effect transistor (MOSFET, MOS-FET, or MOS FET), also known as the metal–oxide–silicon transistor (MOS transistor, or MOS)**,[1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/16328) is a type of insulated-gate field-effect transistor that is fabricated by the controlled oxidation of a semiconductor, typically silicon.

https://computerhistory.org/blog/who-invented-the-transistor/?key=who-invented-the-transistor

"...The ideas of Lilienfeld and Heil and Shockley’s failed early experiments finally bore fruit in 1959 when, working for Egyptian engineer Martin M. (John) Atalla on the study of semiconductor surfaces at Bell Labs, Korean electrical engineer Dawon Kahng built the first successful field-effect transistor (FET) comprising a sandwich of layers of metal (M – gate), oxide (O – insulation), and silicon (S – semiconductor). **The MOSFET, popularly shortened to MOS**, promised a significantly smaller, cheaper, and lower power transistor."